# Can a readonly field be initialized when using DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, initialization, datacontractserializer

`DataContractSerializer` does not call a constructor or invoke field initializers when deserializing:

[DataContractSerializer doesn't call my constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076730/datacontractserializer-doesnt-call-my-constructor)

[Field Initializer in C# Class not Run when Deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419743/field-initializer-in-c-sharp-class-not-run-when-deserializing)

[Setting the initial value of a property when using DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725988/setting-the-initial-value-of-a-property-when-using-datacontractserializer)

Is it possible to initialize a `readonly` field after object deserialization?  Must I abandon that language feature in order to use DataContractSerializer?

Comment: @svick: I cannot think of any mechanism to perform the initalization.  DataContractSerializer uses `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` to "construct" an empty object and does not invoke a constructor or run field initializers.  As far as I understand, a `readonly` field can only be initialized in one of those two ways (but hopefully there's another way I'm not familiar with).

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to deserialize the field. Do I understand you correctly that you for example want to set the field to some default value, that doesn't come from the serialized data?

Comment: @svick: Yes, in my case I have an object whose constructor generates internal state and stores it in a `readonly` field.  I can certainly use the `OnDeserialized` attribute to initialize object state the way `DataContractSerializer` wants me to, but then I see no way to also use the `readonly` attribute to protect that state from post-initialization modification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure doing this is a good idea, but you can change the value of a `readonly` field outside the constructor or field initializer by using reflection.

Putting something like:

```
typeof(MyType).GetField("Field").SetValue(this, value);
```

in your deserialization callback should work.

Comment: I had both thoughts as well... reflection will probably work, but it's probably not a great idea.  Still, perhaps it is the only option.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using `DataContractSerializer` you can serialize a `readonly` field. You can even serialize a non-`public` `readonly` field.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication30
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test a = new Test(1, 2);
            Test b;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));
                ser.WriteObject(ms, a);
                ms.Position = 0;
                b = (Test) ser.ReadObject(ms);
            }
            Trace.Assert(a.Data1 == b.Data1);
            Trace.Assert(a.Data2 == b.Data2);
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Test
    {
        [DataMember]
        public readonly int Data1;

        [DataMember]
        private readonly int _data2;
        public int Data2
        {
            get { return _data2; }   
        }

        public Test(int data1, int data2)
        {
            Data1 = data1;
            _data2 = data2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the object (which was designed in ignorance of the behavior of specific serializers) initializes object state in the constructor, and writes that state into a `readonly` field.  The contents of the `readonly` field themselves are not intended to be serialized.  There is no reason to serialize that internal state because it can always be re-created, and conceptually is private to the implementation of the class.

Comment: @EricJ.Serialization is [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) a process of translating data structures or object state. That's why _it is object fields that are intended to be serialized_, not properties (their values are always recreated from fields) or constructor parameters (the are not necessarily captured by object state). If one needs to recreate object from a set of constructor parameters, this set of constructor parameters should be serialized instead, not object itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clean way to achieve what you are looking for without breaking your design.

Using this method will ensure that your constructor will be called and your readonly field properly set.

---

What you need is to actually serialize and deserialize `[DataMember]` marked fields from a DataModel class.

That will prevent any unintended behavior to happen knowing that DataContractSerializer does not call the constructor when deserializing.

```
namespace MyApp.DataModel
{
    //It is not mandatory to specify the DataContract since a default one will be
    //provided on recent version of .Net, however it is a good practice to do so.
    [DataContract(Name = "MyClassDataModel", Namespace = "MyApp.DataModel")]
    public class MyClassDataModel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool DataMemberExample{ get; set; }
    }

}
```

For deserializing and serializing you can now use this class to hold your values.

Upon loading you can create a new data model object and pass it to your class which needs to have its constructor called.

```
public MyObjectThatNeedToBeConstructed LoadData(){
    // ... 
    // get your reader (Stream) from the file system or wherever it's located
    var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClassDataModel));
    var storedModel = (MyClassDataModel)deserializer.ReadObject(reader);

    return new MyObjectThatNeedToBeConstructed(storedModel);
}
```

Upon saving you can extract the required data from your class that contain the ReadOnly field.

```
public void SaveData(MyObjectThatNeedToBeConstructed myObject){
    // ... 
    // get your writer (Stream) from memory or wherever it's located
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClassDataModel));
    var dataModel = new MyClassDataModel{ DataMemberExample = myObject.DataMember};
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, dataModel);
}
```

Of course, you will have to add an overload to the constructor and you might have to tweak the example a bit, but I think you got the picture.