# Default Values For Missing Data Members In DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

With the below two data members in a DataContract then using a DataContractSerializer, only Name is serialized as expected.  My problem is when I deserialize the file.
"Name" is read and loaded properly but as "Timeout" does not exist I would expect it to stay at the default of "TimeSpan.FromHours(12)".
What infact happens is the DataContractSerializer assigns a value but as it has no value to assign it uses the timespan default of 0.
Is there anyway around this behavour?

```
private string _name;
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name= value;
        }
    }

    private TimeSpan _timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
    public TimeSpan Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeout ;
        }
        set
        {
            _timeout = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would a client have any knowledge of default values of non serialized members? Are you sharing the object definitions?

Comment: This particular contract is strictly an in application contract used for caching certain metadata to disk so as to avoid having to poll a rest service over and over. The reason I want to leave some members out for now as it is moving into Beta and some options I want locked for now.

Comment: I don't think wcf supports writing or reading default values in the wsdl

Comment: I'm not using WCF, just the DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this your answer then

using OnDeserialized

```
[OnDeserialized]
void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
    this._timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
}
```

from here [Setting the initial value of a property when using DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725988/setting-the-initial-value-of-a-property-when-using-datacontractserializer)

Comment: Worked Like a charm thanks-Except I had to use the attribute [OnDeserializing] to set the values before Serialization has started. Then the default values are overwritten if required.