# Default values missing for ServiceStack.XmlServiceClient response

Tags: nunit, servicestack, approval-tests

While using TestCaseSource in unit testing for multiple ServiceStack service clients, deserialized to a string format for the XmlServiceClient does not match the deserialized for JsonServiceClient or JsvServiceClient. The serialization is using the SerializeAndFormat extension method from the ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer class.

Using the [OnDeserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417436/default-values-for-missing-data-members-in-datacontractserializer) fuctionality doesn't seem to provide the same formatted string, as it is missing the default values.

The same JsConfig scope is used with excludeDefaultValues set to false prior to calling the SerializeAndFormat method. The Json and Jsv results match, including the default values, but the xml service client's result does not include them. The object that is not deserializing correctly is a property of a property of the response object and is decorated with this attribute [Serializable].

The response is decorated with [DataContract], [Serializable] and the property objects are both decorated with [Serializable].

How should the objects be decorated so that the serialized response is consistent for all three clients?

```
[DataContract]    
[Serializable]
public class CustomResponse : IMeta, IHasResponseStatus
{
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Meta { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 100)]
    public DataView Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public Summary Summary { get; protected set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class Summary : IResponseStatus
{
    public IEnumerable<HateoasLinks> Links { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string Message { get; protected set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public int? Offset { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public int? Limit { get; set; }
    public string RequestFormat { get; private set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public int? Results { get; protected set; }

    public Parameters Params { get; protected set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Parameters
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Status { get; set; } = "OK";
    public string Sort { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Filter { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue =true)]
    public int? Offset { get; set; } = 0;
    public int? Limit { get; set; } = 10;

    [OnDeserializing]
    void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (!this.Limit.HasValue)
        {
            this.Limit = 10;
        }
        if (!this.Offset.HasValue)
        {
            this.Offset = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

results in:

```
 {
        summary: 
        {
        links: [],
        message: OK,
        params: 
        {
            status: OK,
            sort: "",
            filter: "",
        },
        isSuccess: False,
        status: 200,
        requestTime: 2014-03-14,
        currentPage: 1
    },
    result: 
    {
    }
}
```

but should be
params:

```
{
    status: OK,
    sort: "",
    filter: "",
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code related to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack uses .NET DataContract Serializer for XML so it’s limited to the behaviour and features it provides.

JsConfig only applies to ServiceStack implemented Text Serializers, primarily designed for JSON/JSV and partially used by CSV.